# how to play youtube video using jwplayer in ios ?

Tags: ios, youtube, video-streaming, jwplayer

I am curruntly trying to play youtube video using JWPlayer ios sdk for this i follow step like this:

1) I go on https://www.jwplayer.com/  and create free trial account
2) After i downloaded open source jwplayer demo from [jwplayer SDK](https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer-sdk-ios-demo) and setup app key in info.plist use code like

```
     JWConfig *obj_config = [[JWConfig alloc]init];
         obj_config.file = @"http://youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID";
         obj_config.image = @"Thumbnils_Url";
         obj_config.size = CGSizeMake(320,320);

    self.obj_player = [[JWPlayerController alloc] initWithConfig:obj_config];
    [self.view addSubview:self.obj_player.view];
```

It`s give error like:

> SETUP ERROR {
>       event = onSetupError;
>       message = "Error loading player: No playable sources found"; }

my question is jwplayer support youtube streaming or not?
if supported than how to play youtube video ?

Comment: jwplayer's `file` obviously accepts files only.

Comment: i also try       JWConfig *obj_config = [[JWConfig alloc]initWithContentUrl:@""];

Comment: please read my answer. In short, you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes jwplayer supports youtube videos but HTML5 is the only supported method for Youtube playback in jwplayer.

For you reference 
https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406725-youtube-video-embed

You cannot play youtube videos in mobile through jwplayer.

Comment: Its my pleasure.@ParthBhadaja

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I write this answer, JWPlayer for iOS does **NOT** support YouTube playback, as stated in their [Developer Guide](https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/ios/docs/developer-guide/):

> The JW Player SDK for iOS supports all the features of the JW Player
>   Ads Edition for web, with the following exceptions:
>
> - RTMP streaming
> - Playback of FLV, Vorbis or WebM formats
> - Google Analytics
> - Adobe SiteCatalyst
> - **YouTube integration**
> - VPAID ads

Consider using web-based JWPlayer instead.